# ¿Cual es el mejor Model Field para un point en Django?

Tags: mysql, python, django

Estoy usando django-REST framework y una base de datos mysql, necesito guardar coordenadas en la base de datos, ¿que model field de django debería usar?, yo se que mysql tiene un tipo de dato llamado Point para coordenadas, pero en la documentación de django no encuentro algo parecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que si puedes utilices [Geodjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/). Te facilita mucho la tarea para validar tus campos y a la ves lo puedes complementar con [djangorestframework-gis](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis) para tu api.
En tu modelo quedaría algo como esto:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Problem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.PointField()
```

Answer (score 1):

Django posee una capa de abstracción por lo que las carácteristicas particulares de tu SGBD (Ej. MySQL) no influyen fuertemente en tu modelo de datos.

El tipo de campo que necesitas dependerá de dos cosas fundamentalmente, **precisión y almacenamiento.**

Las alternativas que tienes son FloatField y [DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DecimalField), los detalles específicos de cada uno [se discuten en la documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#floatfield-vs-decimalfield).

Pero si quieres evitar los problemas de precisión de `Float` en su almacenamiento y operación te recomiendo optar por el `DecimalField`, en especial porque puedes especificar en detalle la precisión que deseas en su almacenamiento y carece de errores de redondeo de `Floats`.

Yo en particular, hice un modelo así para almacenar puntos en un espacio 2D para una aplicación geográfica, con precisión hasta `0.000000 - 999.999999` espero que te sirva:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    """
    latitude and longitude specified in Decimal Degrees (xxx.dddddd)
    """
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=6)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)

    def __str__(self):
        return "lat: {}, lng: {}".format(self.latitude, self.longitude)

    def __sub__(self, other_coordinates):
        return abs(other_coordinates.latitude - self.latitude) + abs(other_coordinates.longitude - self.longitude)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.latitude == other.latitude and self.longitude == other.longitude

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)
```

Ahi si quieres modificar la precisión puedes hacerlo cambiando los `max_digits` y `decimal_places` como se explica en la documentación.